# Does Maven need JDK

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven, Java ...when I do a `mvn clean package` on a Java project, it does create the JAR file for me.

But still how can I know if I have JDK or is it still JRE?

I am on OSX 10.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven needs a JDK, and not a JRE.

Do this for more information on which version of Java you have installed:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $PATH
which java
java -version
mvn --version
```

Comment: Thanks, Ok yep it is installed..both JDK and Maven... BUT JAVA_HOME returns Nothing...so still I have some configuration to do to set my JAVA_HOME on OSX ? and without that nothing (EClipse, IntelliJ, etc..) won't really work ?

Comment: You should have the `JAVA_HOME` and `M2_HOME` variables pointing to the locations in which they are installed. You should also have `$JAVA_HOME/bin` and `$M2_HOME/bin` added to (preferably, the beginning) of your `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Maven requires JDK for compilation.

To check if you have JDK compiler you can type: `javac` in terminal.